# Need to initialize a variable again to zero in for loop

Tags: java, loops

This is my code. I need the `i` value to get initialized again to zero when a particular character is deleted from two strings. Here `sb` refers to first string entered by the user and `sb1` refers to second string entered by user. When both the characters are same while comparing, the char should be deleted from both of the strings and the value of `i` should be reinitialized to zero and start comparing from first character of first string with the first char of second string. Everything is working fine but the value of `i` is not initialized again to zero, instead it gets incremented.

```
for (i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    for (j = 0, d = 0; j < sb1.length(); j++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(j)) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            i = 0;
            System.out.println("the buff=" + sb);

            sb1.deleteCharAt(j);
            System.out.println("the buff=" + sb1);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`for` loops have four parts:

- Initialization
- Test
- Increment
- Body

The first three are the three parts you put in `()` after the `if`, separated by `;`, and the fourth of course is the block of code within the loop.

They run like this: Initialization, test, body, increment, test, body, ...

When your code sets `i` to `0` in the body of the loop, that works, but then the increment happens, incrementing `i`. So if you were going to do it that way, before breaking out of the `j` loop you'd need to set `i` to a value such that when the increment happens, it ends up being `0` — that's `-1` in your case.

But in general, if you're playing with the index, `for` may not be the best looping construct to use. In this case, for instance, `while` is probably a better choice, and I don't *think* you have to start again at `0`, it's just that when you delete a character, you don't want to increment your indexes:

```
i = 0;
while (i < sb.length()) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < sb1.length()) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(j)) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            sb1.deleteCharAt(j);
        }
        else
        {
            ++j;
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure why you have a loop *within* a loop at all, though. You haven't said what the loop's supposed to do, but I don't think you need two loops to do it.

For instance, if the goal is to remove common characters from the beginning of `sb` and `sb1`, you don't want two loops for that:

```
i = 0;
while (i < sb.length()) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(i)) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        sb1.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set -1 to i

```
     for (i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for (j = 0, d = 0; j < sb1.length(); j++) {
            if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(j)) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);                   
                System.out.println("the buff=" + sb);
                sb1.deleteCharAt(j);
                System.out.println("the buff=" + sb1);
                i=-1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

so it increments and becomes zero at the restart.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `while` loop, changing the iterator in the `for` loop is a rather bad practise (it is supposed to be constant length loop).

```
int i=0;
while (i < sb.length()) {
    for (j = 0, d = 0; j < sb1.length(); j++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(j)) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);                   
            System.out.println("the buff=" + sb);
            sb1.deleteCharAt(j);
            System.out.println("the buff=" + sb1);
            i=-1; // It will increment few lines lower so we need to make it equal to -1
            break;
        }
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you have made i with post increment operator. So, at the end of the iteration it will increase the value. This is how post increment works. So make it to -1 will solve your problem.

for (i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {

```
        for (j = 0, d = 0; j < sb1.length(); j++) {

            if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(j)) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                i=-1;
                System.out.println("the buff=" + sb);

                sb1.deleteCharAt(j);
                System.out.println("the buff=" + sb1);



                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int z=1;
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
      if (z == 0)
      {
           i = 0;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      {
           if(condition)
           {
                z=1;
           }
           else
           {
                z = 0;
           }

      }
 }
```

Comment: Are you aware that `if(true)` is always... true ? And that your inner loop does not mean anything as there is a `break` statement at the end without any condition for it ?